# Get Notification Message in Activity

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, push-notification

I am allowing user to do `Tap` on `Notification` then `Launching App` and `opening` a particular `Activity`.

In that `Activity`, which I am opening I would like to get `message` which I sent via Notification

**SendNotification(...) method:**

```
private void sendNotification(String messageTitle, String messageBody, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

**AnotherActivity.java:**

```
public class AnotherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);

        // here I would like to get value of messageBody
    }

}
```

UPDATE #1

**sendNotification**(...) {

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("YouTubeActivity", TrueOrFalse);
    intent.putExtra("message", messageTitle);

    ....

    }
```

Tried both the ways in `onCreate()` of **AnotherActivity.java** but did not get the message

```
        String message=getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
        Toast.makeText(YouTubeActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String value = extras.getString("message");
            Toast.makeText(YouTubeActivity.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);
    intent.putExtra("message", messageBody);
```

So your code be like this:

```
private void sendNotification(String messageTitle, String messageBody, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);
    intent.putExtra("message", messageBody);


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

To get the data do this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);

        // here I would like to get value of messageBody
        String message=getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
    }
```

Comment: Tried not getting message

Comment: When you click in notification launch the MainActivity or the AnotherActivity ?

Comment: AnotherActivity.java (OK I got it now, I have to call AnotherActivity.java instead MainActivity.jav) let me try this one.... I'm so stupid for last 2 days I am thinking why I am not getting message.. anyways first let me try and see

Comment: And you can get this `intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);` ?

Comment: Done... I just used AnotherActivity.java instead MainActivity.java... Thanks

Comment: @Sophie no problem :)